# Accessing SharePoint Online from a Windows client

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to access some lists to write data into them from a Windows client (or a service).

I tried the following:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://myhost.sharepoint.com/"))
{
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUserName@domain.com", "SuperSecretPassword");
    Site site = context.Site;
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The result is a 403 error that suggests I am not allowed to perform such requests.

How is it possible to write, update or delete some data in lists in SharePoint Online (aka Office Cloud / Office 365)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SharePointOlineCredentials` to access your O365 tenant. See example below:

```
var targetSite = new Uri("https://Your_O365_URL>");
 var login = "<user@tenant>.onmicrosoft.com";
 var password = "<password>";
 var securePassword = new SecureString();
 foreach (char c in password)
 {
 securePassword.AppendChar(c);
 }

var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSite))
 {
 clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
 Web web = clientContext.Web;
 clientContext.Load(web,
 webSite => webSite.Title);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 Console.WriteLine(web.Title);

Console.Read();

 }
```

Comment: Thx works like a charm! :)

Comment: Glad it helped!