# Microsoft.SharePoint references - address not valid in this context

Tags: visual

When I add the reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint` in VS2013 project (web or desktop) I can't debug and it says

> "address not valid in this context".

Any idea?

Comment: You must use the .Client .dll in solutions not run on a SharePoint server

Comment: you are right. I would like to know if I would have problems when moving a web project with references to microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll to a hosted provider with no sharepoint installed ?. (my idea is to access sharepoint from another site).

Comment: The whole idea of client dll is that you will not need SharePoint installed locally, so you should be fine (as long as you make it easy to change the URL:s used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I was trying to use microsoft.sharepoint dll but it's not the correct, the correct is microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll and .client.runtime.dll, you will need that the project were a .net 4.0 and sharepoint installed in dev machine (I have read about installing a runtime that makes no neccesary to install sharepoint).

you cand find code in this answer

[Accessing SharePoint Online from a Windows client](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100908/accessing-sharepoint-online-from-a-windows-client/100909#100909)